# Call application route method from template

Tags: ember.js

I have an "authenticated" method on my application route that I want to call from any template. I thought that I could just call it and it would bubble up to the application route, but I can't seem to make it work. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, or a better direction to take? Thank you in advance for the help.

**Route**

```
ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  actions:
    authed: Em.computed ->
      firebase = new Firebase "https://sizzling-fire-4457.firebaseio.com"
      firebase.getAuth()
```

**Template**

```
if authed
  h1: link-to 'contacts' | My Site

==outlet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misunderstood some conceptions. Actions are functions that are called when there is an action for instance `click` or `keydown`. They usually do not return anything. You need global property that would indicate whether user is logged in, it would return some value. Properties are stored inside controllers. You have one global controller created by default it's call `ApplicationController`.

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend
    authed: Em.computed ->
      firebase = new Firebase "https://sizzling-fire-4457.firebaseio.com"
      firebase.getAuth()
```

If you would need this property let's say inside IndexController, I would do

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend
    needs: ['application']

    authored: Ember.computed.alias 'controllers.application.authed'
```

Comment: Thank you @estshy. I used something very similar to what you showed. It is good to know that the route properties don't return anything. I think that was the confusing part for me.

Comment: Actually they can return something but it's going to be treated as boolean. If `true` the action is going to bubble if `false` is going to stop.

Comment: So in this case I want to return a boolean. Is there a reason this wouldn't work as a route method then? If I forced it to be a boolean with !!firebase.getAuth() would that work better?

Comment: Yes, there is. To fire an action you need an event (like click). It is going to return boolean value but it is not going to pass it to template. The point is that the ember can treat actions returning `true` especially. Like I said it is going to bubble up. If it is bubbling up you have to return `false` at some point. If you don't it's probably going to bubble infinity and cause some error.